# apt-get update gives errors in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, 17.10, deb, software-sources

When I run `apt-get update` it gives following output:

```
root@V211:~# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list` contains following lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: 17.10 is past End of LIfe and not supported, which is why you get all the 404 errors.  Check the linked duplicate for further assistance on either upgrading or using the old-releases repository.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 means the 2017-October release of Ubuntu (a *year.month* format is used).  It was a standard release having a supported life of 9 months; ie. you were meant to upgrade to 18.04 LTS 6-9 months after 17.10's release.  If you don't like the 6-9 month *release-upgrade* process, you can use LTS or long-term-support releases which have support for 3 (flavor) 5 (main) **years** (or longer in certain circumstances).  17.Oct + 9 months = 2018.July EOL (or 3 months after 18.04 came out)